# Get users from appending text-field

Tags: 2013, column, user, append-changes

Is it possible to get the user inside a appending text field in SP2013?
If so, how do you need to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user is nothing but the user who last modified the item. If you have set version enabled, you can read each version and get the modified by.